# APA Citations - Online Databases

Tags: citations, apa

I'm new to APA and putting together a large report, but having trouble with figuring out the correct citations for some online databases.

Both are government databases where you can search for information or use data to interactively map stuff.

Example:
https://fortress.wa.gov/ecy/approvedwqa/ApprovedSearch.aspx
http://waconnect.paladinpanoramic.com/project/170/13460

Any help here is much appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "Google is your friend" I found 5 examples how to do this with one google search "apa referencing online database".

Comment: Alternatively https://academia.stackexchange.com/ has citation questions

Comment: Where's your APA style guide? If you're writing in a particular style, it's good to buy the guide. (Or do whatever it takes to access it online.)

Comment: Most of the stuff I can find relates to article databases (ProQuest, etc), whereas this is a database of projects.